# Select count of unique values that might appear in different columns

Tags: sql

I am trying to get a count on values that might appear in 3 different columns but only require the count of unique values. Microsoft SQL.
Eg. value X might appear in column A, B, or C or all 3 but need to make sure I only get a unique count of value X no matter what columns it comes under.

Thanks!

Comment: To be clear, are you asking for a count of the number of rows for which at least one of column A, B, or C contains X? It's not OK to double-count a row where column A and column B both contain X, right?

Comment: Could you include a sample table with expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for? This will Count only 1 occurrence per row regardless of how many columns it is found in.

```
SELECT
    ID
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN ColA = 'X' OR ColB = 'X' OR ColC = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ValueCount
FROM
    TABLENAME
GROUP BY
    ID
```

I guess I should show it without the group by too because you don't specify a grouping.

```
SELECT
    ,SUM(CASE WHEN ColA = 'X' OR ColB = 'X' OR ColC = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ValueCount
FROM
    TABLENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to count each individual occurrence of `X` in *any* column `A`, `B`, or `C`, then the following should work:

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN A = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN B = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
    SUM(CASE WHEN C = 'X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM yourTable
```

Comment: Thanks all. Ultimately there are millions of individual "X" and I need a unique count of them all, so I don't think I can specify "X" anywhere. I don't have a table to hand but let's assume we're talking about public keys. In this case however, each key could be in either block a, block b or block c or in all three. I only want each key to be counted only once. Perhaps it's easier if I only have a total count of unique keys. The nice to have would be a subsequent split of the number of keys depending on which block they appear under, no need to display the name of the key, just the count.

Comment: I think I need a select count distinct across multiple columns

Comment: @FlorenceGoy Show us sample input and output which would be very helpful, thanks.

Comment: thanks both for the suggestions and advice, I had to settle for a work around due to lack of time. I'll add a sample input / output to make things clearer next time. Cheers